# Workaround to add repetitive controls to a SharePoint form without InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a SharePoint form with repetitive controls.I'm a SharePoint Online user(Office 365).

I'm looking for a workaround to do this without using InfoPath or any third party software like Nintex. A JavaScript solution would be ideal.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have used stratus forms as a reliable forms solution for sharepoint list forms.

Have a look at the timesheet example for creating a repetitive section on a form.

https://github.com/mrackley/StratusForms

Answer (score 0):

As HarryB sugegsted, StratusForms is the way to go.

StratusForms has discussion/docs forum at ITUnity.com: 
https://www.itunity.com/community/stratusforms

The Main StratusForms site is here:

http://www.stratusforms.com/

Mark made a number of StratusForms videos for YouTube, too.

Your best bet for support is at ITUnity. The examples are sometimes hard to get working, but once you get past the massive documentation gaps, they're pretty nice. Mark is a coder/sharepoint guru, not a tech writer.

The repeating section of the timesheet example is pretty cool.